# How to make an Ajax call to an online web service?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to make an jQuery Ajax call to an online web service. But I am unable to get a succesful response. I am confused why it is giving me an error.

```
        var webMethod = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit?callback=?";
         var soap ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <soap:Body>     <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <Celsius>12</Celsius> </CelsiusToFahrenheit>   </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>';
        $j.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url :webMethod,
              data: soap,
               dataType :"xml",
              contentType:"text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
              cache:false,
              async: false,
            error:function(resp)
            {
                alert("Error :"+$j.parseXML(resp));
            },

        }).done(function(response){

                console.log(response);
                var xmlData =$j(response).find('FahrenheitToCelsiusResult').text();
                alert(xmlData);
            }); 

    });
```

Comment: do you see some errors in console? what is request' http status?

Comment: Just loading http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit?callback=? gives an error. So try that first and then read http://w3fools.com

Comment: Also why soap? Json with Json return

Comment: Please try to use the console, it will show you the error and where the error occurred. You can open the console by pressing F12 in Firefox or Chrome, would not recommend using it in IE. Instead of alert you can console.log things. This will be very useful if you have many things to log or objects to log. When logging objects you can click on them in the console and inspect their members :-)

Comment: i am using xml because i have to work on the web service which accepts xml formate i also have console it is just giving status 200 ok but i cannot find body of requested data in response of webservice.
and when alert shows null error

Answer (score 0):

I can't go to w3schools as it's blocked in China for some reason.

You are trying to parse the response as XML but making a JSONP call. If you're making the request from any site other then www.w3schools.com you have a problem because of the [same origin policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

So the only way you can consume this webservice from JavaScript is if they implement CORS headers and you're not using IE 9 or lower (jQuery does not implement cors in their ajax requests for IE 9 or lower).

If the site doesn't have CORS headers at all then you can install the forcecors plugin for Firefox. After installation choose view => toolbars => addon bar and in the right corner of the screen click on the "cors" text. Now you can make XHR request from anywhere to anywhere but since you need the plugin installed for it to work it's only good for testing and fiddling as you can't expect users of your site to have that plugin installed and active.

You also need to remove the ?callback= or jQuery will treat your request as a JSONP and will fail because it gets an xml response.